# How to restore a window to its orginal state(the same heigth and width as it's before)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, c#-4.0

Here (below sample program) if the notepad is resized--> maximized and then minized. the window position (maximize) is not retained.

I want to retain the window position as it is before minimizing.

i have tried out the below code. Pls help.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(0);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        string processString = string.Format("Untitled - Notepad");
        IntPtr res;
        foreach (Process theprocess in Processes)
        {
            if (theprocess.MainWindowTitle.Contains(processString))
            {
                if (theprocess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                WindowsNativeCalls.SetActiveWindow(theprocess.MainWindowHandle);

                if (theprocess.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if (theprocess.MainWindowTitle.Contains(processString))
                    {
                        WindowsNativeCalls.WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WindowsNativeCalls.WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                        WindowsNativeCalls.GetWindowPlacement(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, ref placement);
                        switch (placement.showCmd)
                        {
                            case 1:// SW_NORMAL
                            case 3:// SW_MAXIMIZE does the job of bring to front

                                WindowsNativeCalls.SetWindowPos(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_NOMOVE | WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_NOSIZE | WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                                break;

                            case 2: // SW_SHOWMINIMIZED 
                                placement.showCmd = 9;
                                WindowsNativeCalls.SetWindowPlacement(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, ref placement);
                                //res = WindowsNativeCalls.SendMessage(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, WindowsNativeCalls.WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)WindowsNativeCalls.SW_SHOWNORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

public class WindowsNativeCalls
    {
        #region Fields

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Hide Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// Show Normal
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    /// <summary>
    /// Minimize Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Maxiize Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    /// <summary>
    /// Activate Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    /// <summary>
    /// Restore Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    /// <summary>
    /// SW_SHOW
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    /// <summary>
    /// Default Window
    /// </summary>
    public const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
    /// <summary>
    /// Close Windows message
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    /// <summary>
    /// Screen Window Position to No Size Change
    /// </summary>
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    /// <summary>
    /// Screen Window Position to No Move Change
    /// </summary>
    public const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    /// <summary>
    /// Screen Window Position to Show Window
    /// </summary>
    public const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    /// <summary>
    /// Maximize Window in Graphics mode
    /// </summary>
    public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    /// <summary>
    /// Resize Windows message
    /// </summary>
    public const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;


    public struct POINTAPI
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    public struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public int length;
        public int flags;
        public int showCmd;
        public POINTAPI ptMinPosition;
        public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
        public RECT rcNormalPosition;
    }
    #endregion

    #region DllImport Functions

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the show state of a window created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window Handle</param>
    /// <param name="nCmdShow">Show state</param>
    /// <returns>Returns True if successful</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets window in Forefront and activates it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window Handle</param>
    /// <returns>Returns True if successfu</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the show state of a window created.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window Handle</param>
    /// <param name="nCmdShow">Show state</param>
    /// <returns>Returns True if successful</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumedWindow lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

    public delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumedWindow callback, ArrayList lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WINDOWINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public RECT rcWindow;
        public RECT rcClient;
        public uint dwStyle;
        public uint dwExStyle;
        public uint dwWindowStatus;
        public uint cxWindowBorders;
        public uint cyWindowBorders;
        public ushort atomWindowType;
        public ushort wCreatorVersion;

        public WINDOWINFO(Boolean? filler)
            : this()   
        {
            cbSize = (UInt32)(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWINFO)));
        }

    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO pwi);

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the window to use its previous position, then don't overwrite the window position information by calling `SetWindowPos()`.

Instead, just minimize the window by calling [`ShowWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) with the appropriate command (i.e. `SW_MINIMIZE`). Then when you restore it, its previous position information will still be there.

**<aside>**
By the way, any particular reason your code is checking both the window handle for `null` and the window title *twice*?

**</aside>**

Comment: Hi Peter, I have read the below lines from msdn.  Controls how the window is to be shown. This parameter is ignored the first time an application calls ShowWindow, if the program that launched the application provides a STARTUPINFO structure. Otherwise, the first time ShowWindow is called, the value should be the value obtained by the WinMain function in its nCmdShow parameter. In subsequent calls, this parameter can be one of the following values.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx   check this link. The taskbar comes up for the first time when we launch the windows. from the next time onwards its not coming. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: @raj: sorry, I don't understand your comment. Your original question did not involve the taskbar at all. If you have a different issue, you should post a new question. The comments are not the correct place to seek advice for additional aspects of your problem.

Comment: Thanks peter will post as a new question

Comment: my question is in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755118/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-when-autohidetaskbar-option-selected-and-a-script-ahk-scr

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch (placement.showCmd) 
                {
                    case 2: // Activates and displays the window -- This case only when the window is minimized.
                        WindowsNativeCalls.ShowWindow(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, WindowsNativeCalls.SW_RESTORE);
                        break;
                    default: // Bring to Front - For all other cases
                        WindowsNativeCalls.SetWindowPos(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_NOMOVE | WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_NOSIZE | WindowsNativeCalls.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                        break;

                }
```

Comment: You've taken care defining symbolic constants, only to use a magic number (`2`) in place of `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`. Are you hoping that noone will ever have to read this code again?

Comment: should have used enums. since it is an existing code, I didn't modify.